# bootstrap toggle with width 100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap toggle plugin [link](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com) and I'd like to know how can set the width 100% like btn-block to occupy the all space of the parent element.
Now I can set the with only with px value.

```
$('.toggle').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'Y',
    off: 'N',
    width: ONLY FIXED SIZE IN PX,
    size: 'small'
});
```

I tried to create a custom class for this but without success.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" name="cb1" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" name="cb2" value="1">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" name="cb3" value="1">
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I do? Thank you

Comment: do you want to set 100% width of input field?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can directly give the `width` in % metrics as well and not just fixed px. So you can change the code to make it look like this.

```
$('.toggle').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'Y',
    off: 'N',
    width: '100%',
    size: 'small'
});
```

Alternatively you can remove the `width` parameter from the `.bootstrapToggle()` method and use it in the HTML as well like so.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="toggle" name="cb1" value="1" data-width="100%">
```

Comment: Is not possibile to use width % with this plugin.

Comment: I seem to have used it here. [Check my Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKRReb)

Comment: Very strange, in my project does not work.. I try to check again. Thank you

Comment: Try to see if your jQuery is being called. Also check my codepen for the JS and CSS resources used. I have also mentioned an alternate method updating my answer.

Comment: I found the error ! in my code I had <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox"...></label>. Now I've deleted and it works! Thank you